# CakePHP: ContainableBehavior Query Structure/Joins

Tags: cakephp, join, model, containable

## My Application's Data Model

- Group hasMany User
- User belongsTo Group
- User hasMany Punch
- Punch belongsTo User
- Punch belongsTo PayPeriod
- PayPeriod hasMany Punch

## Find call

```php
$groups = $this->Group->find('all', array( 'contain' => array(
    'User' => array(
        'Punch' => array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'Punch.payperiod_id' => null
            )
        )
    )

)));
```

## Query Debug

```sql
SELECT `Group`.`id`, `Group`.`name` 
FROM `pclock`.`groups` AS `Group` 
WHERE 1 = 1 ORDER BY `name` ASC

SELECT `User`.`id`, `User`.`name`, `User`.`group_id` 
FROM `pclock`.`users` AS `User` 
WHERE `User`.`group_id` IN (4, 3, 5, 2, 1)

SELECT `Punch`.`id`, `Punch`.`user_id`, `Punch`.`time_in`, `Punch`.`time_out`, `Punch`.`payperiod_id` 
FROM `pclock`.`punches` AS `Punch` 
WHERE `Punch`.`payperiod_id` IS NULL AND `Punch`.`user_id` IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Once my application scales to hundreds of Users each with thousands of Punches, these queries can become very inefficient.  I would expect Containable to perform the following query:

### Query I'd Prefer

```sql
SELECT 
    Group.id, Group.name, 
    User.id, User.name, User.group_id, 
    Punch.id, Punch.user_id, Punch.time_in, Punch.time_out, Punch.payperiod_id 
FROM groups AS Group
LEFT JOIN users AS User 
    ON (Group.id = User.group_id)
LEFT JOIN punches AS Punch 
    ON (User.id = Punch.user_id)
WHERE Punch.payperiod_id IS NULL
```

Is there any way to optimize this?  The join attribute in the options array is seemingly ignored, and doing joins manually without Containable returns results that aren't hierarchical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how containable works. You can use the join params in the find or look up the linkable behavior which does the joins for you.

https://github.com/rafaelbandeira3/linkable

Answer (score 2):

You can join manually:

```
$groups = $this->Group->find('all', array(
    'fields'=>array(
        'Group.id', 'Group.name', 'User.id', 'User.name', 'User.group_id', 
        'Punch.id', 'Punch.user_id', 'Punch.time_in', 'Punch.time_out',
        'Punch.payperiod_id'
    ),
    'conditions'=>array(
        'Punch.payperiod_id IS NULL'
    ),
    'joins'=>array
        array(
           'table'=>'users',
           'alias'=>'User',
           'conditions'=>array(
               'Group.id = User.group_id'
           )
        ),
        array(
            'table'=>'punches',
            'alias'=>'Punch',
            'conditions'=>array(
                'User.id = Punch.user_id'
            )
        )
    )
));
```

Comment: I think that there doesn't make sense to use joins when cake does it for you

Comment: @Jonathan Cake doesn't do the joins (in all cases) when using containable. It performs separate queries.

Comment: Yeah, I am studying about that right now. WHat I mean that there should be a better alternative than typing all associations as joins when you already didi n the model.

Comment: The linkable behavior didn't work for me, do you have any solution beside joins? thank you